# Angular material dynamic radio button able to select multiple but should allow only once in a group

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material, radio-group

I have an angular-material Tree with creating check boxes and radio button dynamically based on array

Array as follows:

```
{
    "Documents": {
      "angular": {
        "src": {
          "core": 0,
          "compiler": 0
        }
      },
      "material2": {
        "src": {
          "button": 1,
          "checkbox": 1,
          "input": 1
        }
      }
    }............................etc
}
```

html part as follows:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
    <div *ngIf="node.type;else other_content"> <!--- node.type == 1 then checkbox!-->
      <mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</div>

<ng-template #other_content><!--- node.type ==0 then radio button!-->
  <mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value=" {{node.filename}}">{{node.filename}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</ng-template>

  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
      <mat-icon>
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.filename}} : {{node.type}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

[Angular Tree Reference Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-tree-simple?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

It looks as follows:

[image]

The issue is that as shown in picture I am able to check all radio button in a particular level of tree. But it should allow only one radio button from radio button group.

The issue occur because of below:

```
<loop .....>

<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value=" {{node.filename}}">{{node.filename}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</loop end>
```

But in single iteration one set of   `<mat-radio-group>` is created but it should create as below:

```
<mat-radio-group>
      loop through <mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

What should I do to make only Radio button can be selected in a particular group?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried putting the mat-radio-group outside of mat-tree? Something like

```
<mat-radio-group>
    <mat-tree>
       <mat-tree-node>
            <mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>
        </mat-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- 
You need to set name to be unique for every radio button.
If there are more radio buttons with the same name they will become a group.
-->
<mat-radio-button
 *ngFor="let btn of this.radioButtons"
 [name]="btn.Id"
 [checked]="btn.checked"
>
</mat-radio-button>
```